# why not called function (forward) is called in pytorch class?

Tags: python, class, pytorch

I have the following simple example code for linear regression as follows.import torch

```
import numpy as np
from torch.autograd import Variable
class linearRegression(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, inputSize, outputSize):
        super(linearRegression, self).__init__()
        self.linear = torch.nn.Linear(inputSize, outputSize)

    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.linear(x)
        return out

x = np.array([1], dtype = np.float32).reshape(-1, 1)
x = Variable(torch.from_numpy(x))

model = linearRegression(1, 1)
model(x)
```

the output is `tensor([[0.4512]], grad_fn=<AddmmBackward>)`.

My question is how the output is made by not `model.foward(x)` but `model(x)`.
In this code I have never called `forward`, but it seems to be called.

Comment: `model.foward(x)` would be a typo. Did you perhaps mean `model.forward(x)`?

Comment: It appears to be registered as a pre-hook to call it when you inherit that module. See https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/module.html#register_module_forward_pre_hook

Comment: on a side note in python classes are by convention PascalCase. https://realpython.com/python-pep8/#naming-conventions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because the dunder method `__call__` of `nn.Module` will internally call its user-defined `forward` method.